bijection from vectors with non-negative integer integer entries to integers
I have the following question. Given a natural number $N$ we construct a set $K$ of vectors of infinite length with non-negative integer entries with a given sum $N$. For example, for $N=3$ the set $K$ consists of vectors like $(0\ldots 0,1,0 \ldots 0,1,0\ldots 1,0\ldots)$, $(0\ldots 0,1,0 \ldots 0,2,0\ldots)$, $(0\ldots 0,2,0 \ldots 0,1,0\ldots)$, $(0\ldots 0,3,0\ldots)$. The question is to find another infinite vector $a$ such that its scalar product with all vectors of $K$ will produce a bijective mapping from $K$ to the set of integers.

"mapping from $K$
to the set of integers". Do you mean non-negative integers?

No, the whole set of integers

Does $a$ have to have integer components?

No such a requirement

Well, I can do it for $N=1$.

Note that, for $N=2$, if $a$ has a non-integer component, then that component must be a half-integer, and then every component must be half an odd integer. Some argument like this may apply for all $N$.

In fact I am interested in the case of large $N$
